# Filter DataFrame String Column with values in List

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am attempting to filter my dataframe column, which is a string field (we're talking paragraphs per record here), with a list of values housed in my list. Here is my current code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Test Data.csv')
test = ['a', 'b']
test = pd.Series(test)
test = list(test.index)
df['string_field'].apply(lambda x:' '.join(x for x in str(x).split() if x in test))
```

However all I'm managing to accomplish is to delete the values in my list from the text in the string field.

Comment: while this technically works, using the same variable name for the collection your iterating over (`x.split()`) and for the item in each iteration (`x for x...`) is a very bad and confusing practice

Comment: @yurib thank you, however this isn't a solution to my problem. On your note, do you have a better solution or best practice?

Comment: that's why it's a comment and not an answer ;) a better practice would be to just pick a different name for one of those variables..

Comment: I see thank you. Also new to stack overflow, didn't realize there was a difference between the two. Thanks for your help, so basically use 'x for y in str(z).split()....)?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're attempting to filter a list of strings using a list of integers...

```
test = ['a', 'b']
test = pd.Series(test)
test = list(test.index)
print test
>> [0, 1]
```

Not sure why you're manipulating `test` this way, if you just keep it as a list (`['a','b']`) it should produce the expected result:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Test Data.csv')
print df

test = ['a', 'b']

df['string_field'] = df['string_field'].apply(lambda s:' '.join(x for x in s.split() if x in test))
print df

>>
  string_field
0      a b c d
1      a 1 b 2
2        ab ba
  string_field
0          a b
1          a b
2
```

Comment: This is close, however it's removing all words in the text field. I need to keep all of the text and keep all rows where values in my list exist.